# Script Witness Not Validating for Multisig

Tags: utxo, script, script-addresses, validation, multisig

I'm getting the following error when trying to consume a UTxO sitting in a multisig script address:

```
[
  {
    "scriptWitnessNotValidating": [
      "74947280b4d63d1051d319d700e21dac50ee858c089378ccc410b568"
    ]
  }
]
```

This is the script I created for requiring 4 of 6 signatures to consume the UTxO:

```
const jsonScript = {
    type: 'atLeast',
    require: 4,
    scripts: [
        {
          type: 'sig',
          keyHash: '6bccf3fc71642dbc8f34deb976784ca636665043ef1384b31cab2524'
        },
        {
          type: 'sig',
          keyHash: 'acfdc19b3081ef21301f76eee0e5e35411b9d2c2b5624e580f36bac4'
        },
        {
          type: 'sig',
          keyHash: 'f03009eb94e1d4a208ccc64bde7e91dc3f6a6c1d8660199fc2f120b8'
        },
        {
          type: 'sig',
          keyHash: '3c76bbfc8af2b0862c3aca122a1d5a4493ee8b2aa2cfb7aadcfdcbc5'
        },
        {
          type: 'sig',
          keyHash: '52a09a992dfbe55f9ec80bc73fecf1bf7f42434c73e8bb79067aaf30'
        },
        {
          type: 'sig',
          keyHash: 'dd31fc7bf8d266eb08f840361ff528108d6689eeb3af96cfa77d8547'
        }
    ]    
};
```

I'm using this function to provide each of the signing keys to the transaction I want to execute:

```
tx.addKeyWitnesses(signingKeys[0]);
tx.addKeyWitnesses(signingKeys[1]);
tx.addKeyWitnesses(signingKeys[2]);
tx.addKeyWitnesses(signingKeys[3]);
tx.addKeyWitnesses(signingKeys[4]);
tx.addKeyWitnesses(signingKeys[5]);
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to consume the right UTxO? Check the index, maybe you are trying to consume the wrong output of that transaction.

Comment: I tried all over again and it worked. I'm not sure if it was that or not but at least I have it right now. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to sort this out.

You can use this library to create the multisig: https://github.com/tango-crypto/cardano-wallet-js

The code I ran was the following:

**multisig.js**

```
const { WalletServer , Seed } = require('cardano-wallet-js');

const data = {
    "type":  "atLeast", //requires at least 4 keys to sign the tx
    "require": 4,
    "scripts":
    [
        {
            "type": "sig"
        },
        {
            "type": "sig"
        },
        {
            "type": "sig"
        },
        {
            "type": "sig"
        },
        {
            "type": "sig"
        },
        {
            "type": "sig"
        },
    ]
};
// generate the native script
const script = Seed.buildScript(data);

const jsonScript = Seed.scriptToJson(script);

console.log(jsonScript);

// get native script private keys (all them will be needed to sign the final tx)
const keys = Seed.getScriptKeys(script).map(k => k.to_bech32());
console.log("keys:", keys);

//Generate script address
const address = Seed.getScriptAddress(script, 'testnet').to_bech32();
console.log("address:", address);
```

The code to sign the transaction is this one (you need to replace every 'XXXX' on `scriptKeys` with your signing keys, and every 'YYYY' on `jsonScript.scripts` with the key hashes of each signature - all this is output of `multisig.js`):

**tx-sign.js**

```
const { WalletServer , Seed , Config, Bip32PrivateKey } = require('cardano-wallet-js');

const scriptKeys = [
    'XXXX',
    'XXXX',
    'XXXX',
    'XXXX',
    'XXXX',
    'XXXX'
];

const signingKeys = scriptKeys.map(key => Bip32PrivateKey.from_bech32(key).to_raw_key());

// get native script (this is the SAME SCRIPT, we're just "loading" it back)
const jsonScript = {
    type: 'atLeast',
    require: 4,
    scripts: [
      {
        type: 'sig',
        keyHash: 'YYYY'
      },
      {
        type: 'sig',
        keyHash: 'YYYY'
      },
      {
        type: 'sig',
        keyHash: 'YYYY'
      },
      {
        type: 'sig',
        keyHash: 'YYYY'
      },
      {
        type: 'sig',
        keyHash: 'YYYY'
      },
      {
        type: 'sig',
        keyHash: 'YYYY'
      }
    ]
};

// set network configuration
let buildOpts = {
    startSlot: 0, 
    config: Config.Testnet,
};

const ttl = 52399446; // slot before the tx should be processed

const CoinSelectionWallet = {
    "withdrawals": [],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "quantity": 10000000,
                "unit": "lovelace"
            },
            "address": "addr_test1xr20j5t970ssz0323tzqqvp3pp02s96yf64zmzj83kksyvx5l9gktulpqylz4zkyqqcrzzz74qt5gn429k9y0rddqgcq2yupvs", // script address
            "id": "d48f256aea384066756be0c11c6e6b8baef8f7ad25ba92b76d1ae3c294443400",
            "assets": [],
            "index": 0
        },
    ],
    "deposits": [],
    "change": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "quantity": 8800000, // fee of 200000 initially
                "unit": "lovelace"
            },
            "address": "addr_test1xr20j5t970ssz0323tzqqvp3pp02s96yf64zmzj83kksyvx5l9gktulpqylz4zkyqqcrzzz74qt5gn429k9y0rddqgcq2yupvs",
            "assets": []
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "quantity": 1000000,
                "unit": "lovelace"
            },
            "address": "addr_test1qpypxf9jma2lkmzwn6nhypmynqpmus7x0ekwp2jfdrxqgm8vecdcssszlmywlyn7h0nkqp9jyk8p7dhjecglhu9m75xq4mwl9v",
            "assets": []
        }
    ]
};

const script = Seed.buildScript(jsonScript);
// for the script witnesses we only need to specify the native script root
const scripts = [script.root];

// build the tx (you can include scripts/signingkeys here, eg: let tx = Seed.buildTransactionMultisig(selection, ttl, scripts, null, sigingKeys, buildOpts);)
let tx = Seed.buildTransactionMultisig(CoinSelectionWallet, ttl, [], null, [], buildOpts);
// add script
tx.addScriptWitness(...scripts);
// add witness
tx.addKeyWitnesses(signingKeys[0]);
tx.addKeyWitnesses(signingKeys[1]);
tx.addKeyWitnesses(signingKeys[2]);
tx.addKeyWitnesses(signingKeys[3]);
tx.addKeyWitnesses(signingKeys[4]);
tx.addKeyWitnesses(signingKeys[5]);
    
const signed = tx.build();
console.log(signed)
```

When you do :

```
tx.addKeyWitnesses(signingKeys[0]);
tx.addKeyWitnesses(signingKeys[1]);
tx.addKeyWitnesses(signingKeys[2]);
tx.addKeyWitnesses(signingKeys[3]);
tx.addKeyWitnesses(signingKeys[4]);
tx.addKeyWitnesses(signingKeys[5]);
```

You are signing with all 6 signatures. You can sign with any 4 you want and the UTxO will be consumed as well. On the contrary, if you provide less than 4 signatures, then the validation will fail.